# why i can't fix this error android.widget,textView cannot be cast to android.widget,button?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-button

This is my first android application, the first page contain 2 buttons, the first button work pretty good. when i click to the second button the application stopped and it's show the error :`android.widget,textView cannot be cast to android.widget,button`

if i try to read the error correctly its telling that: The lines below `Caused by...` tell you where the error was thrown, which is in `Login.onCreate()` on `line 55`. As best I can tell line 55 is:

```
btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFerme);
```

i've checked many similar problem and its gone after they clean project or correct XML layout.
i've try:
-Clean project.
-chekcked XML files.
-Use the XML onClick attribute to create another method
and it's still didn't work. can someome please help me? Thank you.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/in" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Authentification"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#3b3b3b"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="Entrer votre login"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Mot de passe"
            android:textColor="#3b3b3b"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_mdp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="Entrer votre mot de passe"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFerme"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Se connecter"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

edit:

```
 package com.example.gestionincidents;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import com.example.gestionincidents.Login;
    import com.example.gestionincidents.R;



    public class Login extends Activity {
        private static final String strURL = "http://unfmtetouan.com/android_connect/utilisateur.php";
        private EditText inputEmail;
        private EditText inputPassword;
        private Button btnLogin;

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        private static final String ExtraLogin = "Login";
        protected static final String ExtraUser = "UserKey";



        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_login);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_mdp);
            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFerme);

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new Compte().execute();

                }
                });



        }
            class Compte extends AsyncTask<String,String, String> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Veuillez Patienter ...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();

                }


                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                    String result =null;
                    InputStream is = null;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair> ();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("utilisateur",inputEmail.getText().toString()));

                    try{

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();    
                    }catch(Exception exp){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + exp.toString());
                    } 
                    try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);

                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");

                        }
                        is.close();
                        result=sb.toString();

                    }catch(Exception exc){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + exc.toString());
                    }
                    String essai=result.substring(0, 4) ;
                    try {
                        if (result.matches("<br >")){
                             essai=result.substring(0, 2) ; 
                        }
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        int b=jArray.length();



                           JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);


                           final String mot_pass = json_data.getString("mdp").toString();
                           final String login = json_data.getString("Login").toString();
                           final String idu = json_data.getString("id_utilisateur").toString();
                           new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if (mot_pass.equals(inputPassword.getText().toString())){

                                       Intent principale =new Intent(Login.this, afficher_incidents.class);
                                       principale.putExtra(ExtraLogin, login);
                                       principale.putExtra(ExtraUser, idu);
                                       startActivity(principale);

                                       finish();

                                   }else {
                                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                                            public void run() {
                                                alert.showAlertDialog(Login.this, ":(" , "Mot de Passe Incorrecte !" , false);
                                //  hada howa l3adi         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mots de Passe Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                      }
                            }
                        }).start();


                   }catch(JSONException e){
                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                alert.showAlertDialog(Login.this, ":(" , "Login Incorrecte !" , false);
                            }
                        });

                   }


                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog once done
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
    }}
```

Edit 2:

```
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.catours.tourfinder/com.example.gestionincidents.Login}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at com.example.gestionincidents.Login.onCreate(Login.java:55)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
06-11 13:03:52.921: E/AndroidRuntime(5877):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Uninstall your application from emulator or device and install it again.

Comment: i did and it's still show the same error

Comment: then you need to Clean your Project

Comment: i clean it several times. and at each time it's show the same thing

Comment: have you tried it with deleting gen and bin folder and then clean and then run.

Comment: @user3573694 can you send me your code? Let me check importing here in my Editor

Comment: @user3573694 android:id="@+id/btnFerme", is this id in any another xml file? I mean have you given this name to any textView in another xml file? Its taking reference from some other xml.

Comment: yes i delete gen and bin folder but it's still show the error

Comment: @user3573694 can you send me your code? Let me check importing here in my Editor

Comment: check all Your xml files, if anywhere is an error, you cannot comile and recreate R.java. Clean the project will only work well if You have no error inside any xml file....

Comment: okay i will send it to you

Comment: yes you can delete it. thank you

Comment: @user3573694 have you sent it or not yet???

Comment: @user3573694 yes, that was the issue, just change your xml file button id to btnLoginTest and then clean your project and then run

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your **gen** and **bin** folders
2. Clean and build your project
3. Run your project

Comment: it should work since you are accessing button in your code and in your xml it's a button so there is no case of it being a class cast exception

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line `import com.example.gestionincidents.R;` from your import.Clean and Run your project.

Comment: i did delete the line and clean the project but still show the error